# Is there any way to customize the categories that the data-defined override offers?

Tags: qgis, symbology, scale, data-defined-override

My question is if there is a possibility of changing the color scale that the data defines override gives you by default. My data set goes from 0 to 1 and the program defines a color every 0.1, but I need to change this scale for my study. I need them to be different, for example, from 0 to 0.5, from 0.5 to 0.7, etc. Is there any way to modify these ranges?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Graduated Layer Rendering](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#graduated-renderer) and manually define the range (and color) for each category you want:

*Double click an the yelow highlighted values to change the range manually:*

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That was the only way I found :)